# How to remove last <li> child together with it's local storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, removechild

I'm doing a to do list and I want to add, remove and clear tasks together with their local storage. *Add* and *clear* work but I failed to make *remove* work.

I tried using element.lastChild but removing it didn't work.

```js
var last = document.getElementById("list").lastChild.innerHTML;
```

Here is my code

```js
var remove = function(){
    var listItems = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("li");
    var last = listItems[listItems.length - 1];
    last.parentNode.removeChild(last);
    removeStore(last);
   }   

// localStorage
function store() {
    window.localStorage.myToDoList = list.innerHTML;
  }
function clearStore() {
    localStorage.clear();
 }
function removeStore(item) {
    localStorage.removeItem(item);
}
```

Remove works only for removing tasks but I'm getting an error after the first clicking on remove button 
"TypeError: last.parentNode is null" 
and after the last one:
TypeError: document.getElementById(...).lastChild is null

https://codepen.io/aggat/pen/PrQRYj

Comment: Could you post your code on Codepen or anything? I think everyone can help you better, my friend :D

Comment: https://codepen.io/aggat/pen/PrQRYj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your javascript part of the code with my part. The changed part is commented in capitals and explained with the purpose of change.

```
    var add = function(){
        var listItems = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("li");
        var what = document.getElementById('what').value;
        var li = document.createElement('li');
            if (what.length > 0) {
                li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(what));

          list.appendChild(li);
                store()         
                //document.getElementById('what').placeholder = "What do I have to do?";
            } else {
                li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Task number " + (listItems.length + 1)));
                list.appendChild(li);
                store();    

            }   
    } 

    // I HAVE TO CHANGE THE LOGIC OF THIS FUNCTION COMPLETELY
    // THIS FUNCTION TAKES VALUE FROM LOCAL STORAGE, CHECKS FOR EXISISTENCE OF
    // LAST li ELEMENT HTML AND IF FIND IT, THEN REMOVE IT FROM LOCAL STORAGE VALUE
   // AND SET NEW VALUE BACK IN LOCAL STORAGE
    function rem() {
            //var a = document.getElementById("list").lastChild.innerHTML; 
            //localStorage.last = a;
            var aValue = localStorage.getItem("myToDoList");
        console.log(aValue);
            var listItems = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("li");
        console.log(listItems);
            if (listItems.length > 0) {
                var last = listItems[listItems.length - 1];
                if (last) {
                    var lastHtml = last.outerHTML;
            console.log(lastHtml);
                    var indexAtWhichLastElementPresent = aValue.indexOf(lastHtml);
                    if (indexAtWhichLastElementPresent > -1) {
                        // Removes the lastElementHtml part from local storage value
                        aValue = aValue.substring(0, indexAtWhichLastElementPresent) + aValue.substring(indexAtWhichLastElementPresent + lastHtml.length);
                    }

                }
            }
            localStorage.setItem("myToDoList", aValue);
        } 

    var remove = function(){
        var listItems = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("li");
      console.log(listItems);
        var last = listItems[listItems.length - 1];
      rem(); // CHANGED THE CALLING ORDER. FIRST REMOVE DATA FROM LOCAL STORAGE AND THEN ELEMENT WILL BE REMOVED 
      last.parentNode.removeChild(last);

    // TAKE OUT THE REMOVE FUNCTION FROM INSIDE OF THIS FUNCTION SO THAT IT CAN
    // BE USED BY SOME OTHER FUNCTION IN FUTURE

        if (listItems.length === 0){
            alert();
        }
    } 

    var clearAll = function(){
        var myNode = document.getElementById("list");
        while (myNode.firstChild) {
            myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
            clearStore();
        }
        alert();
    }

    // localStorage

    function store() {
        window.localStorage.myToDoList = list.innerHTML;
      }
    function clearStore() {
        localStorage.clear();
     }
    /*function removeStore(item) {
        localStorage.removeItem(item);
    }*/
    function getValues() {
        var storedValues = window.localStorage.myToDoList;
        if(!storedValues) {
          list.innerHTML = '';
        }
        else {
          list.innerHTML = storedValues;
          }
      }
    getValues();

     //modal box
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    //button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    //<span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    //open the modal
    function alert() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    //clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    //clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

Please comment if in case you face any problem in implementing this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your `last` is available only if you have entries in your todo list. Initially, and after clearing all items from your todo list, `last` in your `remove()` function will be `undefined` as your list is empty.

To avoid this error, conditionally check for the presence of entries in your todo list.

```
var remove = function(){
    var listItems = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("li");
    var last = listItems[listItems.length - 1];
    if (last) {
       last.parentNode.removeChild(last);
    }
    ... rest of your code
}
```

And after removing item from your list, set your localstorage with current elements of your list. This will update your localstorage with currrent items in the list.

```
if (last) {
  last.parentNode.removeChild(last);
  window.localStorage.myToDoList = document.getElementById("list").innerHTML; // or call your store(); function
}
```

Hope this is helpful :)

Comment: Thanks, it helps with errors, but I'm still looking for how to remove last localstorage

Comment: After doing `last.parentNode.removeChild(last)`, call the `store()` function one more time to update your localstorage. That's the only thing you're missing.

Comment: So now I have
`code
var remove = function(){
 var listItems = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("li");
 var last = listItems[listItems.length - 1];
 last.parentNode.removeChild(last);

 if (last) {
       last.parentNode.removeChild(last);
    store();
    getValues();
    }   
}`
but it still doesn't remove local storage

Comment: Can i revert back your changes on codepen please? i'll fork your codepen then and share the link here.